# Class in another class, the error as TypeError: Student.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lap' in line 21. s1=Student('raj',2)

Tags: python, oop

```py
class Student:

    def __init__(self,name,rollno,lap):
        self.name=name
        self.rollno=rollno
        self.lap=self.laptop()
        

    def show(self):
        print(s1.name,s1.rollno)

    class laptop:

        def __init__(self):
            self.brand="HP"
            self.CPU="i9"
            self.RAM="8gb"

    

s1=Student('raj',2)
s2=Student("raju",3)


s1.show()


lap1=s1.lap
lap1=s2.lap
```

Comment: You are taking 3 args in your student init (name, rollno, lap) but supplying 2

Comment: I understood, what was error.but not able to complete the code without any error, could you suggest s1=Student('raj',2,____) and s2=Student("raju",3,___)-->what suppose to be written

Answer (score 1):

Your class requires 3 arguments `name,rollno,lap` when you call the class it's only providing 2. if you want to make lap optional, you can make it a keyword argument like `lap=0` then it wont be required when you initiate the class.

Or in your case I think you may just want to take `lap` out of the `__init__` arguments

Comment: would you complete the codes, so that I could understand better manner! for example can you call brand,CPU,RAM